# How to Save Great_Expectations suite locally on Databricks (Community Edition)

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, great-expectations, databricks-community-edition

I'm able to save a Great_Expectations suite to the tmp folder on my Databricks Community Edition as follows:

```
ge_partdf.save_expectation_suite('/tmp/myexpectation_suite.json',discard_failed_expectations=False)
```

But the problem is, when I restart the cluster the json file in longer in the tmp folder. The reason for this I guess is because files that reside in the tmp folder are temporary. However if I try and save it a folder that I know exists on Databricks e.g /FileStore/tables I get the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json'
```

Can someone let me know how to save locally on Databricks please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save_expectation_suite` function uses the local Python API and storing the data on the local disk, not on DBFS - that's why file disappeared.

If you use full Databricks (on AWS or Azure), then you just need to prepend `/dbfs` to your path, and file will be stored on the DBFS via so-called DBFS fuse (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis)).

On Community edition you will need to to continue to use to local disk and then use `dbutils.fs.cp` to copy file from local disk to DBFS.

Update for visibility, based on comments:

To refer local files you need to append `file://` to the path.  So we have two cases:

1. Copy generated suite from local disk to DBFS:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('file:///tmp/myexpectation_suite.json', "/FileStore/tables")
```

2. Copy suite from DBFS to local disk to load it:

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json", 
  'file:///tmp/myexpectation_suite.json')
```

Comment: Hey Alex, gonna try your suggestion now with dbutils.fs.cp. Gonna to have remind myself how to use dbutils.fs.cp .. unless you have a quick answer on how to copy with dbutils.fs.cp? :-)

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm getting the following error when I try to copy with dbtuils.fs.cp

```java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/myexpectation_suite.json```

My syntax is as follows:

```dbutils.fs.cp('/tmp/myexpectation_suite.json', "/FileStore/tables")```

Comment: you need to use `file:` for local files: `dbutils.fs.cp('file:///tmp/myexpectation_suite.json', "/FileStore/tables")`

Comment: ok, using 'file' successfully copied over. Thanks. However, when I try to read the copied json using the syntax below I get error:

```validation_results = ge_partdf.validate(expectation_suite='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json', only_return_failures=False)
GreatExpectationsError: Unable to load expectation suite: IO error while reading dbfs:/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json```

```validation_results = ge_partdf.validate(expectation_suite='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json', only_return_failures=False)```

Comment: Hi Alex, I think you know what my objective here .. its to be able to save expectation_suite to dbfs so that I can read it back without having to save it everytime.

Comment: you also need to use either `/dbfs/FileStore`,  or on community edition - use `dbutils.fs.cp` again, but in opposite direction

Comment: Going to attempt this on a Azure Databricks, as I'm not entirely sure what you mean by using dbutils.fs.cp in the opposite direction :-) BTW, sorry for poor way I'm writing these descriptions. I'm still not sure how to do carriage returns on SO

Comment: On Azure you just need to append `/dbfs` to DBFS  path... By opposite way I meant to swap arguments when you need to copy from DBFS to local file system: `dbutils.fs.cp("/FileStore/tables/myexpectation_suite.json", 'file:///tmp/myexpectation_suite.json')`

Comment: ok, I followed your instructions on Azure and it was successful. Thanks. On the Community Edition, I successful in copying in the opposite direction as you suggested. However, I thought the objective was the following:
```dbutils.fs.cp('file:///tmp/myexpectation_suite.json', "/FileStore/tables/")```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240236/discussion-between-patterson-and-alex-ott).

Comment: you are copying `file://` -> `/FileStore` when you first generated that file. And `/FileStore` -> `file://` when you need to use it